# Sending data from client side Fetch to server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, fetch

I am using Nodejs, Express, MySQL, body-parser and EJS.

What I am trying to do is, when someone press on a button, it sends a `PUT` request which will update the counter by 1, I am trying to send the `ID` of the pressed button so it can be incremented by 1.

```
    app.put("/toolong", function(req,res){

             console.log(res.status(200).json({voteNum: 5}))           
          }
        )
```

The Fetch:

```
function upvote(click){
// when the upvote button is clicked
let idOfClicked;
console.log(event.target.attributes[1].value)
idOfClicked = event.target.attributes[1].value

fetch(`/toolong`, { method: 'PUT', data: {id:9} })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(jsonRes => {

    console.log(jsonRes.voteNum) // gives 5

  })
}
```

I am trying to send the variable `idOfClicked` from the Fetch to my `app.put` so I can do a SQL query which will use that variable.

I assume you are able to do it, the "`data`" key in the fetch is something I tried from seeing some examples but I wasn't able to send it through

Comment: Can you try with passing it in body, like this :- fetch(`/toolong`, { method: 'PUT', body: {id:9} })

Comment: @MariyaJames  I changed it, but how do I get the actual body in my app.put? Trying with req.body.id doesn't show me the value

Comment: It should be there. try console req.body. Is it empty?

Comment: @MariyaJames req.body is sadly empty

Comment: @MariyaJames  Nevermind, I fixed it, I had to write, I didn't have "headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })" in the fetch(i put it after the "body")

Answer (score 0):

It's a `body` key instead of `data`.

Comment: I changed it, but how do I get the actual body in my app.put? Trying with req.body.id doesn't show me the value

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was I didn't have `"headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })"` in my app.put, I placed it after my `"body"`