# Fetch does not POST from the Client-Side to the Server-side (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fetch, ejs

**Problem:** I am using the following code provided by StackOverflow [members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72053456/18423528). I like the code, and I wish it worked, but it did not, as I will explain:

**The Purpose:** Take input from the Client-Side, modify it with JavaScript, then POST the modified variables to the Server-Side (Node.js/Express).

**The Code** (credit to [kwh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057469/18423528)):

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function customSubmit() {
      const name = document.getElementById('name').value + ' mock';
      const city = document.getElementById('city').value + ' mock';
      fetch('/posty', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, city })
      })
    }
  </script>
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); customSubmit()">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input id="city" name="city" type="text">

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>  
</body>
```

I have node.js and express.js serverside, and I have not installed node-fetch. I use EJS as templating engine/file for HTML and JS for the Client-Side.

Client side code:

```
app.post('/posty', (req,res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
 
})
```

which returns an empty object in the console (Linux terminal):

```
{}
```

Now if I replace the following line in the code:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); customSubmit()">
```

with

```
<form action="/posty" method ="POST">
```

I will get a non-empty object in the console:

```
{ name: 'John', city: 'Berlin' }
```

However, this is not the solution because I have to modify the person's name and the city before POSTing it to the Server-Side (Node.js).

**Discussion:**

I have not installed node-fetch for node.js. Even, If I installed it, I would have to import the module in a node.js server file that runs on the Server-Side, not on the Client-Side. I cannot see the point of installing node-fetch on node.js to use fetch() to POST in HTML/JS code running on a compatible browser on the Client-Side.

Maybe something is missing in the given codes above, either on the Server-Side or Client-Side, or both. I would appreciate it if someone could point that out. Also, I want to thank [kwh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057469/18423528), who provided the clean and compact code and helped organize my research to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.
I find the solution with the help of two StackOverflow members and one of the other posts on [StackOverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705919/sending-data-from-client-side-fetch-to-server-side):

I had to add the following line to fetch() block in the code that [kwh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72057469/18423528) suggested (Client-Side):

```
headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
```

Also, I added the following line to the code on the Server-Side as [Ifaruki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72064321/18423528) suggested:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

So one line of code was missing on the Server-Side and one on the Client-Side. I needed both.

Thanks again for your fast response and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use parsed the body before your routes? You can do it with `express.json()`

```
app.use(express.json())
app.post('/posty', (req,res) => {

    console.log(req.body)
 
})
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I added app.use(express.json()) as you suggested and I still get an empty object { }.

Comment: @EricandWeb okey hmm.. and i guess its at the top, before your routes? You can open your Developer tools. Then you go to the network tab. Then you click on send to trigger the post request. The request should appear in the network tab. Now check if the post data is actually sended to the server without an error

Comment: Thanks, Ifaruki. There were two lines missing, one was that you pointed out above on the Server-Side and one as I explained in the final answer that I found on the Client Side. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

javascript is much faster than the dom, thats why you need to let the browser to render the dom first then to exec the js. it is done by this

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  // content is loaded
  
  const form = document.getElementById("id-of-yow-form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //add yow code
  });

});
```

make sure to add the same id to yow form tag

```
 <form id="id-of-yow-form">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text">

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input id="city" name="city" type="text">

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```